# Probability and Covariance given joint pdf

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint PDF $f(x,y) =
2$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ y ≤ 1$, and $0$ elsewhere.

a) Find $Pr(X +Y ≤ 1)$

b) Find covariance of $X$ and $Y$

I'm not really sure how to find that probability...the bounds are confusing me a bit. Similar with the covariance. Are the bounds just the $1\times1$ square?

Answer (score 0):

The joint support, $\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\}$, is a right-triangle.   $\triangle(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)$ to be precise.

As they are jointly uniform distributed, the probability may be found directly by geometry -- just sketch a graph of where $y\leq 1-x$ intercepts the triangle (a smaller triangle) and compare.   You might also use this to determine bounds for an integration, for practice.

---

For the other part, the covariance will be determined by integrating the relevant functions over the given support. $$\displaystyle\int_0^1\!\!\int_0^y \ldots~\mathrm d x\mathrm d y$$

Comment: So, to find P(X+Y≤1) could my X-bounds of integration be 0 and 1 and Y-bounds be 0 and 1-x?

Comment: The probability is measured over: $0\leq x\leq 1$ , $0\leq y\leq 1-x$, *and* $x\leq y\leq 1$ .  The intersection of the event description and the support.

Comment: ALso, when I calculate cov(X,Y), I am getting a negative number. I have EX=2/3, EY=1, EXY=1/4, so Cov(X,Y)= -5/12

Comment: So, I get a probability of 1 when I integrate with thouse bounds, is that correct?

Comment: No, the correlation is positive because $\mathsf EX$ and $\mathsf EY$ are smaller than that.  (Reality check: do you expect $Y$ to lie on the edge of the support?)

Comment: Ok....so what exactly am I doing wrong to get a negative covariance?

Comment: My psychic senses tell me ... some sort of error durring the integration ?